# How can I access multiple instances of mainWindow in an Electron App?

Tags: electron

How do I create a functioning electron app with multiple instances of the mainWindow? Here's a very simple app with a mainWindow that just has two buttons. One to create a new mainWindow instance, and one to close the current window.

```
// main.js
const { app, ipcMain, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let mainWindow;

function main () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    tabbingIdentifier: 'todoTab',
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  mainWindow.loadFile('renderer/index.html');
  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.setTitle("Todo-" + mainWindow.id)
    mainWindow.show();
  })
  mainWindow.mergeAllWindows();
}

app.on('ready', main);

ipcMain.on('newListWindow', main);

ipcMain.on('closeWindow', function(event){
  mainWindow.close();
});
```

- In the above file I set mainWindow as a global variable.
- Adding a tabbingIdentifier property and chaining the mergeAllWindows() method will automatically create multiple tabs in the display if more than one window is opened.
- Each mainWindow instance is assigned an id by Electron. If only one instance is open the id is 1. For simplicity I set the mainWindow title to be "Todo-" + the mainWindow.id (so Todo-1 for the first window, Todo-2 if I open a second).
- When the newListWindow button is clicked the "main" function gets called creating a new instances of mainWindow.
- When the closeWindow button is pressed the mainWindow instance is closed.

The HTML file with the two buttons (abbreviated to just the body element)

```
// renderer/index.html
<body>
  <h1 class="text-center">Todo List</h1>
  <button id="new-list-btn">New Todo List</button>
  <button id="close-btn">Close List</button>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

The ipcRenderer. Listens for the button clicks and sends a message to main.js.

```
// renderer/index.js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

document.getElementById('new-list-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  ipcRenderer.send('newListWindow');
});

document.getElementById('close-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  ipcRenderer.send('closeWindow');
});
```

The above code will create multiple Todo windows and display them on different tabs. Each list title (Todo-1, Todo-2, etc) is displayed. The problem is, the last one opened is the only active one. So if I open three todos, then go to any one of them and click the close button, only the third window will close, regardless of which one I was in. Then the other two will throw an error if I try to close them saying the object was destroyed. Which makes sense. So how do I code this so if that whichever instance tab I am in is the one that I close. And when I close it the next tab I am in becomes the valid mainWindow object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to deal only with the *focused* BrowserWindow in `'closeWindow'` callback

Use [`BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowgetfocusedwindow) static method

```
ipcMain.on('closeWindow', function(event) {
  const current = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()
  if (current) current.close()
})
```

Comment: This is almost it. Only problem is it will only work if I close that last window opened. So if I have three instances of mainWindow open and I try to close the first or second instance it will just do nothing. That solves part of the problem but I'd like to close the first and second windows when I click the close button. A slight modification to your code will do that. If I set mainWindow to the focused window instead of const current and then mainWindow.close() it works like I want. If you want to change your answer to that I'll accept it.

Comment: IDK how you tested it but I experience the opposite of "will only work if I close that last window opened. So if I have three instances of mainWindow open and I try to close the first or second instance it will just do nothing". - it does close the proper tab for me on 7.1.1

Comment: My mistake, your way does work. So does they way I outlined. Okay, then, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pergy's answer works as requested but I'll post this answer as well since it's what I'm actually using, and there's no other documentation on how to do this that I could find. The difference is small but this seems more direct:

```
ipcMain.on('closeWindow', function(event) {
  mainWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
  mainWindow.close();
})
```